# Telegram-bot stores same user message

Tags: php, mysql, bots, telegram

I'm fighting a problem, which i can't come to an end with programming a chatbot for the company i work for.
I want the User to type in /register and then the Bot asks for your EMail so he can send you a generated Token to your Mail.
Instead of saving the EMail it safes /register as the EMail in my MYSQL database.
I've searched the web for solutions but didn't found any that fix this problem.

I'm getting the updates via webhook.

The token and Website are set too so please don't mind that.

I Thank you for fast replies in advance.

With best regards 
Niklas

P.S. Sorry for my bad english I hope you understand what I want my bot to be like

```
<?php
    function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max)
{
    $range = $max - $min;
    if ($range < 1) return $min; // not so random...
    $log = ceil(log($range, 2));
    $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
    $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
    $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
    do {
        $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
        $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
    } while ($rnd > $range);
    return $min + $rnd;
}

function getToken($length)
{
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
    $max = strlen($codeAlphabet); // edited

    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0, $max-1)];
    }

    return $token;
}

$connection = mysqli_connect ('localhost','xxx','xxx','xxx','3306');
if(!$connection){
    die('Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden!' .mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Erfolgreich Verbunden';
$auswahl=mysqli_select_db($connection,"id3057414_testuser");
    if(!$auswahl)
    {
        die('Zugriff auf die Datenbank nicht möglich! Existiert sie wirklich?');
    }


$update = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);

$chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];;

$text =  $update["message"]["text"];

$updateid = $update["update_id"];

$messageid = $update["message"]["message_id"]

file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=$messageid!");


$lesen = "SELECT * FROM Kundenalarm";
if($text=="/register")
{


    sleep(3);
    $name = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $name = json_decode($name, TRUE);
    $name =  $name["message"]["from"]["first_name"];
    $aufnahme = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO Kundenalarm (Name,Kennung,GeräteID,Alarm) VALUES ('$name','$chatID','','')");
    if(isset($name))
    {
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=Gib deine Email ein!");

    sleep(5);

    $email = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $email = json_decode($email, TRUE);
    $Mail= $email["message"]["text"];



    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=$Mail!");


    if(!$aufnahme)
    {
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=Dein Name wurde nicht in die Datenbank aufgenommen !");

    }
    else
    {

        file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=Dein Name wurde nun in die Datenbank aufgenommen!");
    }
    }
}

if($text=="/aktivieren")
{
    $atoken=getToken(5);
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=$atoken");
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT EMail FROM Kundenalarm WHERE Kennung = '$chatID'");
    $zeile = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $empfaenger= $zeile->EMail;
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=$empfaenger");
    mail($empfaenger,"Aktivierungstoken Kadsoft","$atoken","Von KadsoftBot generiert!");
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=Email gesendet!");


}

mysqli_query($connection,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$resultat = mysqli_query($connection,$lesen)
    or die ("Anfrage Fehlgeschlagen");

print_r($text);

print_r($chatID); 

if($text=="Hallo"||$text=="Hi")
{
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=Hallo schön dich hier zu sehen!");

    }

if($text=="Wie ist das Wetter?")
{
    file_get_contents($website."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=Heute ist es bewölkt!");
}
?>
```